# docker-compose down not removing anonymous volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have my docker-compose as below:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
  
  backend:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - upload:/app/upload
    depends_on: 
      - mongodb

  frontend:
    build: ./client
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  data:
  upload:
```

After running `docker-compose up -d` it creates 4 volumes:

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     86ade5422b5ec2ab35fc3b2ea76099596d8b4a36f96c4428fbab4559ae5cff74
local     de8c5f9680c5c4f73b6a3d4a1b3d4d2f962cc498d34a49dbfbbbda4cc7652288
local     easyhome_data
local     easyhome_upload
```

The 2 anonymous volumes seem to target to the `/data/configdb` and `/app/node_modules`

If I shut it down then run it again `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` it will create 2 more anonymous volumes identical to the previous two

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     5a1ead27ac78cee770aad636c156818c246377132b50a8b773b35be46146195f
local     86ade5422b5ec2ab35fc3b2ea76099596d8b4a36f96c4428fbab4559ae5cff74
local     bc3063ff80f63f9e7ed5c1e319ee43a6d92ccdb2bfa9aec7e6be35378a566638
local     de8c5f9680c5c4f73b6a3d4a1b3d4d2f962cc498d34a49dbfbbbda4cc7652288
local     easyhome_data
local     easyhome_upload
```

I dont want to run `docker-compose down -v` because it will remove my 2 named volumes as well. Please provide guidance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly ask docker-compose to remove volumes:

```
docker-compose down -v
```

Reason is: volumes are meant to persist data useful to the user.

Read more about available options:

```
docker-compose down --help
```

Output:

```
Usage:  docker compose down

Stop and remove containers, networks

Options:
      --remove-orphans    Remove containers for services not defined in the Compose file.
      --rmi string        Remove images used by services. "local" remove only images that don't have a custom tag ("local"|"all")
  -t, --timeout int       Specify a shutdown timeout in seconds (default 10)
  -v, --volumes volumes    Remove named volumes declared in the volumes section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                          attached to containers.
```

Comment: but like I said `docker-compose down -v` would also delete 2 named volumes (easyhome_data, easyhome_upload) that I need to persist. Actually, they are the only volumes I have, the other 2 anonymous volumes I have no idea about them, but docker will always create 2 more like that whenever I run my container

Comment: There is no built in functionality for that. With ‘docker run’ you can specify ‘—rm’ to remove anonymous volumes. In docker-compose not. ‘Docker volume prune’ cleans up unused volumes but for your case you should start a temporary container and mount the 2 named volumes so they look busy, then you can prune the volumes. Seems to me a lot of work with little benefits

Comment: Actually I can `docker volume prune` during `docker-compose up` and those 2 anonymous volumes will be deleted while 2 named volumes are running. But I was thinking if I have other useful named volumes, for example, from other projects, they would also be deleted. Might not be a good practice.

Comment: I would say don't worry about it. Just be aware of the possibilities for when you will need it: like you have strange issues and you want to run with a clean situation. If the allocated space for docker gets filled, then docker will complain and then you can clean up. You might also want to check for stopped containers with `docker container ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your named volumes external and then use `-v` flag without losing them:

```
volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: easyhome_data
  upload:
    external:
      name: easyhome_upload
```

BTW you need to create volumes manually if they don't exist (e.g before the first time you `docker compose up` your project):

```bash
docker volume create easyhome_data
docker volume create easyhome_upload
```